# What does "Print the string using twice the length as the width." mean?

Tags: c

I can't ask my lecturer at this moment seeing as where i am it's late at night and on the weekend.

this is the question:
"Write a program that inputs a string from the keyboard and determines the length of the string. **Print the string using twice the length as the width."**

The bolded bit is the part i don't understand.

Comment: With `printf()` you can specify the minimum width to use to print something, and it pads out any extra with spaces. He may mean this.

Comment: We're not the ones that gave you that question so we can't exactly guess what your lecturer had in mind.

Comment: i am not sure how can you get the width of a string ? you should really ask some co-student.

Comment: Haha yeah, i'm really not to sure what the "width" is here, so far i used strlen() to define the size, but not sure what i do from their

Answer (score 4):

He means to print with padding
e.g.

```
Hello <-- not padded
     Hello <-- padded in 10-char field, right justified
```

Comment: ohh ok i get ya.
say i had a string "str", would using strlen() be appropriate to find the size?